# Create session from button name which is $row?

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli

What I'm trying to do, I don't even know if it's possible.

I'm loading up a database table that will have a button next to each row.

That button has an ID and Name that is equal to my row's id.

```
echo "<td><button id='" . $row->id . "' name='" . $row->id . "'/>$row->id</button></td>";
```

Now, I want a session to be created with that id number so I figured I'd input this code

```
if (isset($_POST["' .$row->id .'"])) { 
$_SESSION['reportidtest'] = $_POST[".$row->id ."];
header(location: records.php);
}
```

That way I could create the session, go to record.php, and then on load textboxes will be echo'd with the values of the rest of my columns in that particular row.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a much more simpler way of doing this?

This would be perfect only for it don't load the values on the records.php, it only has blank textboxes:
https://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/3064-basic-php-system-view-edit-add-delete-records-with-mysqli/